# Convert YYYYMM to MMMYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a period 201604 (nvarchar). Is there a way that I can convert `201604` to `APR16`?

Comment: You should probably add which version of SQL Server you are using to the question - Tim's answer below assumes 2012 or newer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `CONCAT` is the problem - added in 2012. You could of course just use `+` to concat strings. I wasn't having a dig, just as the answers started pouring in, I thought we should get OP to clarify :)

Comment: Backlinking http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83591/convert-yyyymm-to-mmmyy

Comment: I don't understand why you even need to do this.

Comment: @coredump Probably something that is in an existing database which needs to be sanitised. You wouldn't believe how many methods people have devised to avoid using DATETIME.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the `DATENAME` & `SUBSTRING` functions, like this:

```
declare @str nvarchar(50) = '201604'

select UPPER(left(datename(mm,cast(@str+'01' as date)),3))+substring(@str,3,2) --APR16
```

Answer (score 17):

It is a bit ugly, but you can't use any of the built-in date formatting stuff as is. Feel free to swap out the case statement for a join if you have a month names table, etc.:

```
DECLARE @exampleVal NVARCHAR(6) = '201604';

SELECT CASE SUBSTRING(@exampleVal, 5, 2)
         WHEN '01' THEN 'JAN'
         WHEN '02' THEN 'FEB'
         WHEN '03' THEN 'MAR'
         WHEN '04' THEN 'APR'
         WHEN '05' THEN 'MAY'
         WHEN '06' THEN 'JUN'
         WHEN '07' THEN 'JUL'
         WHEN '08' THEN 'AUG'
         WHEN '09' THEN 'SEP'
         WHEN '10' THEN 'OCT'
         WHEN '11' THEN 'NOV'
         WHEN '12' THEN 'DEC'
       END +
       SUBSTRING(@exampleVal, 3, 2)
```

Comment: This answer is the easiest on the eyes, and would be even nicer if placed into a user-defined function.

Comment: @Thomas Well, maybe it is actually better this way. I mean, which human wants to see "APR16" instead of "April 2016"? So most likely, the thing which actually takes the result of this function doesn't care about regional/language settings.

Comment: @Thomas I know - but where was that specified in the question?

Comment: @dim Diamond Comic Distributors ordering codes contain for example "AUG16".

Comment: @DamianYerrick And you wouldn't want the french ordering website to translate that to "AOU16" since it is a *code*. That's my point.

Comment: And, by the way, in french, the june and july months begin with the same three letters (JUI). So, definitely, any solution that relies on the locale configuration for this would actually just screw things up in this particular case.

Comment: @Bridge, I have tried your answer and this works well. However, it would be lengthy if we are using it in store procedure. Thank you :)

Comment: @RedRocket that's not a bad thing.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

Add '01' (as first day of month), so convert your varchar to datetime and get the datename of the month:

```
declare @myperiod nvarchar(10)
SET @myperiod = '201604'

SET @myperiod = @myperiod + '01'

SELECT UPPER(SUBSTRING(DATENAME(month, CONVERT(datetime, @myperiod)), 1, 3)) +
  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(year, CONVERT(datetime, @myperiod))), 3, 4)
```

Comment: + UPPER and would be ok

Answer (score 7):

Add 01 at the last, so that it changes to a valid date format. Then use the datename function:

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(10)='201604'

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,@STRING+'01') +' '+SUBSTRING(@STRING,3,2)
```

Output:

```
April 16
```

Comment: Just add UPPER and LEFT `SELECT UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,@STRING+'01'),3)) +SUBSTRING(@STRING,3,2)` and preciously what OP requested :)

Answer (score 6):

In two lines:

```
declare @napis varchar(6)='201506'
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(month, @napis+'01'),3)) + SubString(@napis,3,2)
```

Comment: That feeling, when you give absolutely right answer first, but credits go to another one.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is by using [`Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx) and [`DateFromParts()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228(v=sql.110).aspx). This will work in [SQL Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2012) or newer versions:

```
Declare @Period NVarchar (6) = N'201604'
Declare @Format NVarchar (5) = N'MMMyy'

Select    Upper(Format(DateFromParts(Left(@Period, 4), Right(@Period, 2), 1), @Format))
```

> APR16

Answer (score 5):

Use simple this

```
declare @test nvarchar(max) = '201604'

select left(DATENAME(month, @test +'01'),3) + SubString(@napis,3,2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
DECLARE @Date varchar(6) = '201604'

SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(9), CAST(@Date +'01' as Date), 6), 4, 7), ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one..

```
DECLARE @DATE NVARCHAR(6) = '201604'
SELECT datename(MONTH,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(DATE,LEFT(@DATE,4)+'.'+RIGHT(@DATE,2)+'.01',102),102))
```